# IIS FTP with umlaut chars in user and password - cannot connect

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, passwords, ftpwebrequest

```
public void FTPOps()
{
    string ftpUserID = "ftpätest";
    string ftpPassword = "sampleäpass";
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP =
      (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://<SERVERURL>:<PORT>"));
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID.Normalize(), ftpPassword);
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
    reqFTP.Proxy = null;

    var response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
}
```

Results in

> (530): Not logged in

with following error stack.

```
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.FTPOps()
at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The same credentials work when the same FTP server is accessed via Windows Explorer (not IE).

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is indeed buggy and while announces UTF-8 support, it does not accept UTF-8 encoded username. Interestingly, it seems that there's no problem with UTF-8 password.

One need to use legacy "Ansi" encoding for the username.

I do not think you can make `FtpWebRequest` use "Ansi" encoding for the username.

You better change the username.

If you cannot change the username, you have to use another FTP client that is able to workaround the IIS bug.

For example, [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) will automatically fallback to "Ansi" encoding for credentials, when authentication with UTF-8 encoding fails. For this to work, the default legacy "Ansi" encoding must be same on local machine as on the server (Windows-1252 in your case)

```
// Set up session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    PortNumber = port,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "ftpätest",
    Password = "sampleäpass",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

Example of log:

```
> 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067 USER ftpätest
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067 331 Password required
> 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067 PASS sampleäpass
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067 530-User cannot log in.
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067  Win32 error:   The user name or password is incorrect. 
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067  Error details: An error occurred during the authentication process.
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.067 530 End
. 2017-06-22 07:54:45.128 Login data contains non-ascii characters and server might not be UTF-8 aware. Trying local charset.
> 2017-06-22 07:54:45.128 USER ftpätest
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.129 331 Password required
> 2017-06-22 07:54:45.129 PASS sampleäpass
< 2017-06-22 07:54:45.129 230 User logged in.
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks Martin for pointing me in the right direction. I will evaluate the winSCP assembly.